# Romantic movie about a guy trying to find the woman in his dreams by piecing together faces from magazines

Tags: story-identification, movie

The film is about a love story that starts with:

1. A guy dreaming about the one who will love her and he tries to figure out how she looks like.
2. He starts searching for different shapes of eyes, nose... etc. and starts to collect them from magazines and pictures.
3. As soon as he created the picture that he sees in his dreams, he started to look for her in real life till he finds her.

It's an English language film and if I'm not mistaken from around the '80s/'90s.

---

*The Truman Show* has been suggested by a user in an answer below, but, unfortunately, that isn't it.

Comment: If you add a mysterious power surge bringing the woman to life, you've got Weird Science.  But I suspect the 'sees it in his dreams, searches until he finds her' qualifies it as prophetic dreaming and so possibly fantasy by default.

Comment: Hello Sylvia, welcome to [fantasy.se]. Could you please [edit] your question to add details to show that the film you're looking for is indeed science fiction or fantasy? And may I invite you to take the [tour]?

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for all your efforts helping me find this movie. But unfortunately, it is not Truman .

Comment: If he dreamed about the woman, then constructed her in a virtual implanted memory session, you've got Total Recall.

Comment: None of this seems to be SF/F-related.

Comment: @MeatTrademark that depends. Out of the 3 answers, 2 are SF/F related (_The Truman Show_ is squarely on topic, while _Still Breathing_ is asserted by the answerer to be (slightly) on topic as well).

Comment: @SQB The OP said The Truman Show is not the answer, and that's as close as we get to SF&F.

Answer (score 54):

This sounds awfully similar to

## [The Truman Show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Truman_Show)

> 1. *A guy dreaming about the one who will love her and he tries to figure out how she looks like.*

Sylvia, the woman, had appeared in Truman's past and [tried to reveal that he was actually in a TV Show](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J9yMFmavfz8). However, the production crew took her away and kicked her off the cast. This could be quite easily mistaken or misremembered as a dream, given the flashback nature of the scene.

> 2. *He starts searching for different shapes of eyes, nose... etc. and starts to collect them from magazines and pictures.*

Truman, the protagonist creates a collage from magazine images of Sylvia. He hides the collage at his office away from his wife, buying the magazines with the women's faces "for his wife" when he in fact is simply making the collage

[image: Collage of face]

Truman believes that, as Sylvia said, he is in fact in a TV show. As such he begins to orchestrate his escape. The film concludes with him escaping the giant dome, and Sylvia running to go meet him, as can be seen in the below video.

---

#### Plot Summary (from Google)

> He doesn't know it, but everything in Truman Burbank's life is part of a massive TV set. Executive producer Christof orchestrates "The Truman Show," a live broadcast of Truman's every move captured by hidden cameras. Cristof tries to control Truman's mind, even removing his true love, Sylvia, from the show and replacing her with Meryl. As Truman gradually discovers the truth, however, he must decide whether to act on it.

#### Trailer:

Comment: The person that asked this question is named Sylvia... is this real life?

Comment: I don't agree with "Truman believes that ... he is in fact in a TV show". Sylvia's rushed explanation, though she mentions "set" and "fake", is very confusing. The way I interpret the film, he never really knows what his predicament is (until the final scene), just that too many things are really weird and everyone he's ever known except Sylvia is trying to restrict him. But he believes/hopes that there's something else to find, a way out of whatever it is, and something to Sylvia's advice to "come find me."

Comment: @aschepler it was my very quick write-up of “he begins to believe he isn’t in fact leading a normal life and that he’s being watched/surrounded by actors. This becomes clear when a lamp falls, the elevator is a set, etc. etc.

Comment: In case you didn't see it, the OP has commented to confirm that it's *not* Truman :-(

Answer (score 13):

You're describing the plot of ***[Still Breathing](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0120211/)*** from 1998. From [Rotten Tomatoes](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/still_breathing):

> **This romantic fantasy [...] stars Brendan Fraser as Fletcher McBracken, a starry-eyed San Antonio puppeteer who**, like his father and grandfather before him, **has a mystical vision of the woman he's fated to marry.** Believing that she'll be found in "Formosa" (the one-time name of Taiwan), Fletcher books a flight. During a stopover in L.A., however, he learns of a trendy bar called Formosa and decides to check it out. Sure enough, Fletcher sees his dream girl, Rosalyn Willoughby (Joanna Going), a con artist on the lookout for a new mark, a millionaire from Texas.

Fletcher tries to recreate her face by **making various collages based on his visions of her (from the eyes, noses, lips etc. of famous women that he cuts out of magazines and such).** You can
see him making these collages in [the trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XBPQdY50MOE), around 0:16. And yes, this one kinda fits into Fantasy; IIRC he sees things in his visions that he couldn't possibly have known about her. The movie is currently available on Vimeo and also on Youtube (in parts). The poster (From *TV Guide*):

[image]